# Intellij python no recoginiize lib

Tags: python, plugins, intellij-idea

I use intellij with python plugin.
when I want to import python libs like 
    import random
I got editor error.
    No module named random less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

when I run the code every thing is ok
what can I do to make the intelij recognize this libs?

Comment: Do not put a space in the name of the python files that you want to import. What is your error? Your traceback?

Answer (score 3):

You may have fixed this by now, but I was having the same problem and finally solved it, so I figured I'd post the solution for anyone who came here by Googling/Binging the error message:

I went to File > Project Structure > Modules, highlighted the main module, then pressed the plus sign and then "Python" under "Framework".

Hope that helps you or someone else.

Comment: For me, working in django, it was File > Settings > Project Structure. Then I marked the django project root as a source. Good to go.

Comment: Working in PyCharm 4, I fixed the same problem by selecting a version of Python from the dropdown in File > Default Settings > Default Project > Project Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

may be my intellij version is different with you guys.

on Windows platform I fix this problem by:

1.File > Project Structure > Modules

2.on the module's dependencies panel,change the module SDK from JDK to python

3.done